# Upgrade path from .NET 1.1 to .NET 3.5. How to do?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, .net-1.1

I use C# with the .NET 1.1 Framework for a Windows application. We have a requirement to upgrade it to .NET 3.5.

1. Is it possible to upgrade the code directly to 3.5 (or)
2. Should we follow 1.1 to 2.0 to 3.5?

Which method is more suitable?

Comment: Upgrade directly.... You will find that the language and libraries have changed a quite a bit.

Comment: Any reason you're not updating straight to .NET 4.5? Why use a version which is still 7 years old?

Comment: It *could* be that XP support is required - since (as you no doubt know) [XP doesn't support .NET 4.5](http://channel9.msdn.com/Forums/Coffeehouse/Why-is-XP-Support-for-NET-45-not-happening), but then again, XP itself isn't supported.

Answer (score 3):

Simply convert one of your projects to .NET 3.5 and see what happens. I would even suggest to use 4.5 since that will make your code more future proof. Start from the UI project and work your way down.

Usually your code will work. There are quite some adjustments made in the framework, so if you happen to use some deprecated feature, you need to rewrite your code. Usually the compiler sill suggest you what to do or read.

You would probably want to use new features introduced since .NET 1.1, like generic lists, etc. This will need a further review than just converting your code.

Comment: We tried the conversion Wizard available in Visual Studio 2010, and it was targeting 2.0 by default. So is it ok if we change it to target 3.5? And for now the requirement is for 3.5.

Comment: @samr how 3.5 and not 4.5 can be the requirement? .net 3.5 was released a very very long time ago (2007, or in other words, 8 years ago!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!)

Comment: @samr: That is okayish. I would agree with Matias though. You should really upgrade since .NET 3.5 is starting to get ancient.

Comment: @samr: Need more help? If not, please accept the answer.

Comment: Can you please tell me whether conversion wizard would work for directly converting it to 3.5, i could see that visual studio is targeting 2.0 by default.

Comment: I think it only converts the Visual Studio projects. Not the code as far as I know. .NET 2 is at least one step closer to .NET 3.5.

Comment: @samr: Need more help?